# Intent action and intent extra are interchangeable?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, intentservice

I am developing an android service.
I want basically to have three state for the service: DEFAULT, FOOTASK and BARTASK.
What I mean by "state" is basically that my service run some code (DEFAULT) and the user has to the option to either add a supplementary task (FOOTASK or BARTASK).

So, I was wondering if I should simply add the enum as extra and then and of course then get the extra in the service and handle it there:

```
AwesomeEnum awesomeEnum = intent.getSerializableExtra("AwesomeEnum");
handleEnum(awesomeEnum);
```

Or if it would be preferable to use intent action like:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null) {
            if(action.equals("START_FOOTASK")){
                
            }
 if(action.equals("STOP_FOOTASK")){
                
            }
                if(action.equals("START_BARTASK")){
                
            }
 if(action.equals("STOP_BARTASK")){
                
            }
```

Comment: It is all up to you. Just do what you like. Do today this tomorrow that for a change.

Comment: So they are indeed interchangeable in this case scenario?

Comment: I only said that you can use both approaches.

Comment: Which approach would you personally use?

Comment: Sorry, i have no 3-state services.